MuleSoft 4.6.9 - Stored Procedure in Oracle with XMLTYPE - javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException
When I try to update the Runtime version from 4.4.0 to 4.6.9 and Mule Maven Plugin (MMP) from 3.5.4 to  4.3.0 the execution of the application shows: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException
Apache Maven 3.9.9 (8e8579a9e76f7d015ee5ec7bfcdc97d260186937)
Maven home: C:\Users\ag\scoop\apps\maven\current
Java version: 11.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Users\ag\scoop\apps\openjdk11\current
Default locale: pt_BR, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
...
...
...
...
...
...
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.612 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-12-16T08:41:39-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:4.3.0:process-classes (default-process-classes) on project mule-example-database-oracle-xmltype: Execution default-process-classes of goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:4.3.0:process-classes failed: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:4.3.0:process-classes (default-process-classes) on project mule-example-database-oracle-xmltype: Execution default-process-classes of goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:4.3.0:process-classes failed: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:333)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute(MojoExecutor.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.access$000(MojoExecutor.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor$1.run(MojoExecutor.java:162)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.execute(DefaultMojosExecutionStrategy.java:39)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:118)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:906)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:283)
    at org.mule.tooling.maven.embedded.runner.MavenBuildRunnable.run(MavenBuildRunnable.java:84)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
    at org.mule.tooling.maven.embedded.runner.EmbeddedMavenRunner$1.run(EmbeddedMavenRunner.java:54)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-process-classes of goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:4.3.0:process-classes failed: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2(MojoExecutor.java:328)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException
    at org.mule.tools.api.util.XmlFactoryUtils.createSecureDocumentBuilderFactory(XmlFactoryUtils.java:74)
    at org.mule.tools.api.util.XmlFactoryUtils.createSecureDocumentBuilderFactory(XmlFactoryUtils.java:28)
    at org.mule.tools.api.packager.sources.DefaultValuesMuleArtifactJsonGenerator.toDocument(DefaultValuesMuleArtifactJsonGenerator.java:132)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.tryAdvance(HashMap.java:1728)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:632)
    at org.mule.tools.api.packager.sources.DefaultValuesMuleArtifactJsonGenerator.doesSomeConfigRequireEE(DefaultValuesMuleArtifactJsonGenerator.java:107)
    at org.mule.tools.api.packager.sources.DefaultValuesMuleArtifactJsonGenerator.setBuilderWithDefaultRequiredProduct(DefaultValuesMuleArtifactJsonGenerator.java:66)
    at org.mule.tools.api.packager.sources.AbstractDefaultValuesMuleArtifactJsonGenerator.setBuilderWithDefaultValuesNotPresent(AbstractDefaultValuesMuleArtifactJsonGenerator.java:131)
    at org.mule.tools.api.packager.sources.AbstractDefaultValuesMuleArtifactJsonGenerator.generateMuleArtifactWithDefaultValues(AbstractDefaultValuesMuleArtifactJsonGenerator.java:111)
    at org.mule.tools.api.packager.sources.AbstractDefaultValuesMuleArtifactJsonGenerator.generate(AbstractDefaultValuesMuleArtifactJsonGenerator.java:64)
    at org.mule.tools.api.packager.sources.AbstractDefaultValuesMuleArtifactJsonGenerator.generate(AbstractDefaultValuesMuleArtifactJsonGenerator.java:47)
    at org.mule.tools.api.packager.sources.MuleContentGenerator.copyDescriptorFile(MuleContentGenerator.java:225)
    at org.mule.tools.maven.mojo.ProcessClassesMojo.doExecute(ProcessClassesMojo.java:82)
    at org.mule.tools.maven.mojo.AbstractMuleMojo.execute(AbstractMuleMojo.java:61)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:126)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException
    at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(JXDocumentBuilderFactory.java:380)
    at org.mule.tools.api.util.XmlFactoryUtils.createSecureDocumentBuilderFactory(XmlFactoryUtils.java:49)
    ... 42 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[DEBUG] Shutting down adapter factory; available factories [file-lock, rwlock-local, semaphore-local, noop]; available name mappers [discriminating, file-gav, file-hgav, file-static, gav, static]
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'file-lock' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'rwlock-local' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'semaphore-local' factory
[DEBUG] Shutting down 'noop' factory

 The application uses Spring Beans to connect to an Oracle Database because of the usage of a Stored Procedure with XMLType parameter.
I have an example of the project published on GitHub, but the main code is:
pom.xml
with spring beans and XMLParserV2 dependency
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- -->
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-example-database-oracle-xmltype</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule-application</packaging>
    <!-- -->
    <name>mule-example-database-oracle-xmltype</name>
    <!-- -->
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <app.runtime>4.6.9</app.runtime>
        <mule.maven.plugin.version>4.3.0</mule.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- MUnit Maven Plugin - BEGIN -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLines>
                        <!-- BEGIN XML Parser v2 - xmlparserv2.jar - Reference: https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/1.14/database-connector-troubleshooting#troubleshoot-oracles-xml-extensions-using-system-properties -->
                        <argLine>-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl</argLine>
                        <argLine>-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl</argLine>
                        <!-- END XML Parser v2 - xmlparserv2.jar -->
                    </argLines>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- MUnit Maven Plugin - END -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <sharedLibraries>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.oracle.database.xml</groupId>
                            <artifactId>xdb</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.oracle.database.xml</groupId>
                            <artifactId>xmlparserv2</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                    </sharedLibraries>
                    <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.39</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>23.6.0.24.10</version>
            <!--            <scope>runtime</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>xdb</artifactId>
            <version>23.6.0.24.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlparserv2</artifactId>
            <version>23.6.0.24.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-apikit-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-spring-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-db-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.4</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>anypoint-exchange-v3</id>
            <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
            <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v3/maven</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>

Mule Configuration File
Implementation of stored procedure and configs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule
    xmlns:spring="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring"
    xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring/current/mule-spring.xsd">

    <configuration-properties file="common-config.yaml" />

    <spring:config
        name="Spring_Config"
        doc:description="beans.xml"
        files="beans.xml" />

    <db:config
        name="Database_Config_OracleDataSource"
        doc:description="DataSource ref: OracleDataSource | beans.xml">
        <db:data-source-connection dataSourceRef="OracleDataSource" />
    </db:config>


    <flow name="scheduler.stored-procedure-in-out-xmltype">
        <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler">
            <scheduling-strategy>
                <fixed-frequency
                    frequency="10000"
                    startDelay="5000" />
            </scheduling-strategy>
        </scheduler>
        <set-variable value='#["username" ++ ((now() as Number {unit:"seconds"}) as String)]' doc:name="username" doc:id="855a01c0-bb8a-4a5d-bdfe-afe484a8c62b" variableName="username"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="payload/json - Mock">
            <ee:message>
                <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    username: vars.username,
    name: "Name Surname",
    social_name: "Name",
    gender: "M",
    birth_date: "2024-12-31"
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <ee:transform doc:name="payload/text">
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
ns xsi http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
ns xsd http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
output text/plain
---
write(
    {
    Root
        @(('xsi': xsi), ('xsd': xsd)): {

    username: payload.username,
    name: payload.name,
    social_name: payload.social_name,
    gender: payload.gender,
    birth_date: payload.birth_date

    }
}, "application/xml", { indent: false})

]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <db:stored-procedure config-ref="Database_Config_OracleDataSource" >
            <db:sql ><![CDATA[{
CALL CREATE_PERSON_FROM_XML( :IN_P_PERSON_XML, :OUT_P_RESPONSE_XML)
}]]></db:sql>
            <db:input-parameters ><![CDATA[#[{
    IN_P_PERSON_XML: payload
}]]]></db:input-parameters>
            <db:output-parameters >
                <db:output-parameter key="OUT_P_RESPONSE_XML" type="SQLXML" />
            </db:output-parameters>
        </db:stored-procedure>
        <logger
            level="INFO"
            doc:name="payload"
            message="#[payload]" />
        <ee:transform doc:name="response">
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(read(payload.OUT_P_RESPONSE_XML, 'application/xml'))]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
</mule>

beans.xml
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd">

    <bean id="OracleDataSource"
        name="OracleDataSource"
        class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
        <property name="URL" value="${dbOracle.url}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${dbOracle.user}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${dbOracle.password}"/>
        <property name="implicitCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</beans>

To run on Studio it's necessary to inform:
-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl

More about: Troubleshoot Oracle’s XML Extensions using System Properties (docs.mulesoft.com)
I have the need to update an application from Runtime version 4.4.0 to 4.6.9 because of the end-of-support.

Why does Mule Runtime 4.4 have a shorter Standard Support Period?
Edge and LTS Releases for Mule | MuleSoft Documentation

Some other links related:

Using SQL XMLType in Mule 4 | MuleSoft Help Center (help.mulesoft.com)
"Invalid column type" error when calling Oracle Stored Procedure with XMLTYPE parameter | MuleSoft Help Center (help.mulesoft.com)
XMLTYPE cast exception c3p0 pool Oracle Database | MuleSoft Help Center (help.mulesoft.com)


Please put the relevant parts of the code in the question. [so] questions should be self contained. Read [MRE].

@aled I change the question and include the code following the guide you shared.

The error message doesn't give much detail. Are the more lines of the error? What are the previous lines? Also try executing Maven with debug logging (mvn -e...) to see if more details appear.

@aled I executed with -e -X and update the question

Which version of JDK are you using to build the project?

Also why did you add those JVM arguments?

This is necessary because of the reflection for XML Parser that Mule uses and the other necessary for Oracle when added the dependency xmlparserv2. For more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005901/duplicated-definition-for-identifiedtype Some articles about XMLType: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Using-SQL-XMLType-in-Mule-4 / https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Invalid-column-type-error-when-calling-Oracle-Stored-Procedure-with-XMLTYPE-parameter / https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/XMLTYPE-cast-exception-c3p0-pool-Oracle-Database

more about xmlparserv2: https://docs.mulesoft.com/db-connector/latest/database-connector-troubleshooting#troubleshoot-oracles-xml-extensions-using-system-properties:~:text=%2DDjavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory%3Dcom.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl%0A%2DDjavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory%3Dcom.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl

@aled JDK 11 with Anypoint Studio 7.20 and maven 3.9.9. I added to the question more context about the version and also add hyperlinks about the JVM arguments

Have you tested without using those JVM arguments?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
